# Error In Spyder After Anaconda Install

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, spyder

I just installed Anaconda.  I already had Spyder 3.0.0 installed on my Windows 8.1 (64 bit).  I also already had Python 3.4 installed.  But, after installing Anaconda, I went into Preferences and pointed the Python executable to the Anaconda3 folder to utilize the 3.5 version.  But when I started up Spyder again, got the following error:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\PIL\Image.py:81: RuntimeWarning: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Python.
RuntimeWarning
C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\PIL\Image.py:81: RuntimeWarning: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Python.
RuntimeWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\start_ipython_kernel.py", line 187, in 
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in 
import jupyter_client
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in 
import zmq
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 66, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 27, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\WinPythonbit.4.4.2\python.4.4.amd64\lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: Module use of python34.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a copy of the what was in the Console of Spyder:

Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:81: RuntimeWarning: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Python.
  RuntimeWarning

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

- rename your directory "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2" in "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2bis"
- relaunch your Anaconda Spyder
- if it doesn't help, rename it back to "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2"

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure how/why that would invoke python 3.5, but I tried it and that made no change or error.